# Color cells in Excel based on certain values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of 200 cells in Excel. I put in names and would like the text color in the cell or the background of the cell to change according to the name written. I use about 25 names.

Comment: use conditional formatting

Comment: Please be more clear so we can figure something out ...

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question. Excel's built in [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx) feature is far better for this scenerio than any code you would write

Comment: @pnuts what version of Excel are you using?  I don't think there has been a limit since Excel 2003

Comment: @pnuts I do not have Excel 2007 on my machine to verify, but I seem to  recall having more than 4 conditions and 4 different colors in Excel 2007 before, so I am skeptical of the article.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use Excel's conditional formatting feature.   You can look at help to figure out how to do this.  You can also find various 
[documented examples](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel)

Example:
[image: SU488776 example]

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting would be best for this, but if you'd like a VBA alternative you can record a macro in the developer tab and edit it under "modules" in the "project" sidebar. Then under `ThisWorkbook` in the Project sidebar put the code into a `SheetChange` event.

You need to change the two dropdown menus above the text area, the left one needs to be set to `Workbook` (only option typically), the right one needs to be `SheetChange` Then you can use this simple code for as many names as you like. Keep in mind there are many ways to do this.

You can put as many `ElseIf's` in between the `if` and `else` as you like.

```
Sub Macro

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

    Range("A" & i).Select

    If ActiveCell = "Name1" Then

        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 12

    ElseIf ActiveCell = "Name2" Then

        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    ElseIf ActiveCell = "Name2" Then

        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 11

    Else 

        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15

    End If

End Sub
```

using select in code is not the best programming practice, but this is a small amount of data so it is alright. Hope this helps!

Comment: Better option would be to do this automatically by handling the worksheet change event so the colors will automatically update when the sheet is changed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that is a good point. This code would be much more effective under the worksheet changed event

Comment: Added some additional instructions on how to put code into a `SheetChange` event which will automatically run the included code when any change happens on the sheet.